# Search bar does not appear in ios

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have page controller in which I added two tableviews. In each header of tableview search controller added, also viewForHeader method return "Recent" and "Other" view's.

My problem is the search bar does not appear when the search bar clicked.
It appear to move up, I cant see what I am typing there.
There may be the possibility that the search bar is hidden behind "Connection","Message" tab.

How to keep search bar at same position when keyboard become first responder?
any help will appreciated.

[image]

Comment: for bringing subview to front you can use 'bringSubViewToFront' method .

Comment: post the pic where u see the searchbar!!! Use view debugger to see if searchbar is behind the view!!!

Comment: this pic after click in search bar. other wise it sit between recent and connection ,message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u used below lines of code at `ViewDidLoad`

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:searchBarRef]; // add this line where ever u need..!

-(void)loadSearchBar {

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; 

}
```

Call this `loadSearchBar` method at `ViewDidLoad`.

This will add search bar to `TableView`.

Comment: Try above solution..! Instead of search controller in each header view.