# Display search bar view correctly in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use a UISearchDisplayController and its SearchBar like the picture :

[image]

As you can see, the view which need to be over the search bar is not correctly placed because of the view before the search bar that need to be here, but I don't know how can I move it.

I have already this code :

```
@implementation MySearchDisplayController

- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setActive: visible animated: NO];

    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated: NO];
    [self.searchResultsTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 32, 320, 476)];

    [self.searchContentsController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

@end
```

How can I fix it ?

I specify that if I delete the blue view behind there is no problem so it's the cause of the problem, but I need to put the view at this place.

Comment: you want to change y position ?

Comment: Yes I want that the clear view overlaps my search bar

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34312847/3901620

Comment: I try your answer but this not solve my problem. The cause is my view (the blue one behind) cause if I delete it there is no problem.